# How to compare the property of object entries of 2 length arrays and merge into one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, backend

I am trying to compare `values1` and `values2` by their property and the values. If the value of the `name` property matches up with each other, I want to push the property and value to value3.

But I am getting this error: Cannot read property 'age' of undefined

```
const values1 = [
  { name: 'dog', surname: 'good', skills: 'programming' },
  { name: 'cat', surname: 'soft', skills: 'engineer' },
  { name: 'elephant', surname: 'big', skills: 'programming' }
]

const values2 = [
  { name: 'cat', age: '12' },
  { name: 'elephant', age: '13' },
]

const values3 = values1.map((value1) => {
  return Object.assign(value1, { age: values2.filter(value2 => value2.name === value1.name)[0].age })
})

console.log(values3)
```

This is the result I would like to return.

```
{
name: 'cat',
surname: 'soft',
skills: 'engineer'
age: '12'
},
{
name: 'dog',
surname: 'good',
skills: 'programming',
},
{
name: 'elephant',
surname: 'big',
skills: 'programming'
age: '23'
}
```

Comment: how about object with name `dog`. do you want to exlucde it in values3?

Comment: since ```dog``` is not in ```values2``` It can be ignored. like a condition is passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
const values1 = [{
    name: 'dog',
    surname: 'good',
    skills: 'programming'
  },
  {
    name: 'cat',
    surname: 'soft',
    skills: 'engineer'
  },
  {
    name: 'elephant',
    surname: 'big',
    skills: 'programming'
  }
]

const values2 = [{
    name: 'cat',
    age: '12'
  },
  {
    name: 'elephant',
    age: '13'
  },
]

const values3 = values1.map((value1) => {
  const sameObj = values2.find(value2 => value2.name === value1.name);
  if (sameObj) {
    return { ...value1, age: sameObj.age }
  }
  return value1;
});

console.log(values3)
```

Comment: Hey I realize I made a mistake in the question. Could you check again?

Comment: ok, let me check it.

Comment: Could you check my answer again.

Comment: excellent! it worked. this is a larger project of mine and this code was just an example. On my project the ```age``` is undefined. do you know why that might be?

Comment: You're welcome, is your data structure the same as you put in the question?

Comment: no its different

Comment: would you like put an example of your project's structure?